# grub-reboot from Windows

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I have a dual boot setup on my desktop machine, and currently Linux is the default OS, so unless I intervene during boot, it'll boot to Linux. I have a small script to reboot to windows if I'm logged in on Linux, by running `sudo grub-reboot 2 && reboot`, and I'm wondering if I can do something similar from Windows. This will allow me to make Windows my default OS, without sacrificing the ability to easily switch to the secondary OS with a simple script.

I realise this may be impossible or inadvisable, as I know Windows has a habit of not cooperating in multi-boot situations, so feel free to point me at something that says it can't be done, or can't be done yet.

**Summary:** is there a script I can run from Windows, similar to `grub reboot 2` on linux, that will change the boot priority for the next reboot only, to enable a quick switch to my secondary OS?

---

### Addendum: use cases

I hope you'll excuse the repetition, I want to be thorough. All I'm lacking is the "**Reboot to Linux**" script.

#### Current situation

Linux is the default OS, and I have a script to swap to Windows.

- *I am using Linux currently and want to switch to Windows*. I run the script on my desktop labelled "Reboot to Windows". My computer restarts and Windows is selected. I do not intervene. It loads into Windows. Next time I reboot after this, Linux is still the default selection.
- *I want to run Windows*. I turn my computer on, and Linux is selected on the boot screen. I do not intervene in time, and it loads Linux. I run the script on my desktop labelled "Reboot to Windows". My computer restarts and Windows is selected. I do not intervene. It loads into Windows. Next time I reboot after this, Linux is still the default selection.
- *I am using Windows currently and want to switch to Linux*. I reboot my computer. My computer restarts and Linux is selected. I don't intervene. It loads into Linux.
- *I want to run Linux*. I turn my computer on, and Linux is selected on the boot screen. I don't intervene. It loads into Linux.
- *I want to run Windows*. I turn my computer on, and Linux is selected on the boot screen. I intervene and select Windows. It loads into Windows.

#### Preferred situation

Windows is the default OS, and I have a script to swap to Linux.

- *I am using Windows currently and want to switch to Linux*. I run the script on my desktop labelled "**Reboot to Linux**". My computer restarts and Linux is selected. I do not intervene. It loads into Linux. Next time I reboot after this, Windows is still the default selection.
- *I want to run Linux*. I turn my computer on, and Windows is selected on the boot screen. I do not intervene in time, and it loads Windows. I run the script on my desktop labelled "**Reboot to Linux**". My computer restarts and Linux is selected. I do not intervene. It loads into Linux. Next time I reboot after this, Windows is still the default selection.
- *I am using Linux currently and want to switch to Windows*. I reboot my computer. My computer restarts and Windows is selected. I don't intervene. It loads into Windows.
- *I want to run Windows*. I turn my computer on, and Windows is selected on the boot screen. I don't intervene. It loads into Windows.
- *I want to run Linux*. I turn my computer on, and Windows is selected on the boot screen. I intervene and select Linux. It loads into Linux.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but grub can be configured to boot by default to the latest entry chosen.

Comment: I'm effectively asking for a "reboot into Linux" script to run on windows. I don't want to change any defaults, only to change OS for the next reboot. I'll add a use case to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled on it while looking for the same thing. I dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10. Ubuntu is configured as the default selection in grub. Having to manually choose from the grub menu is an annoyance, since my laptop is normally connected to a docking station with the lid closed. If I want to boot to Windows, I run `sudo grub-reboot 0 && sudo reboot now` where 0 is the grub menu item number for Windows on my system. The issue is if I'm in Windows and want to reboot to Windows. I have to open the laptop and choose manually on the grub menu, or boot to Ubuntu and use `grub-reboot` to boot yet again.

With some research and experimentation, I now have a working solution. Note that this is tested only on my system, where I have grub properly configured to allow `grub-reboot` to work as described. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43226) for the proper settings for that. My linux partition is ext4.

From my linux system, I made a recursive copy of `/boot` in my home directory. I then ran `grub-reboot 0` and did a recursive diff of `/boot` and `~/boot`. I found that the only changed file was `/boot/grub/grubenv`. This is the grub [environment block](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Environment-block.html) file and it contains exactly 1024 bytes of text, with `next_entry=` and a filler line at the end of all `#` to get it to 1024 bytes. `grub-reboot 0` simply changes it to `next_entry=0` and adjusts the length of the filler line to keep the file 1024 bytes.

OK, seems simple enough then. The only potentially tricky part is getting read/write access to your linux partition containing `/boot` from within windows. On Windows 11, WSL2 allows mounting ext4 (and perhaps other) partitions. For windows 10, some options are [here](https://losst.pro/en/how-to-mount-ext4-in-windows-10-11). I am using Paragon's [Linux File Systems for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) (not free, but not expensive.)

With that solved, I wrote a bash script to do essentially what `grub-reboot` does. Yes, I realize something like Powershell would perhaps make more sense for a windows tool; I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. Bash was easier for me, and I use cygwin on windows all the time anyway. (I was unable to read the linux partition, mounted on D with the linuxfs-windows driver, from WSL.) Plus it allows me to use the same driver script from either windows (cygwin bash) or ubuntu. Note that the script contains options for testing before committing to anything; `--dry-run` will leave the new grubenv file in `/tmp` and not change your actual copy. `--diff` will diff the old and new (`--diff` by itself outputs the diff and updates your actual file; `--diff` with `--dry-run` spits out the diff and the updated content, without changing anything.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# win-grub-reboot
#
# Update the linux grubenv file, typically in /boot/grub/grubenv, to set the 'next_entry' to the
# specified value. This does essentially what 'grub-reboot' does - set a one time entry for the
# next boot. See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/grub-reboot.8.html.
#
# While it could be used from linux, it would be better to use grub-reboot in that case, of course.
# This is intended to be used in windows, from a bash shell such as cygwin or WSL. It requires
# that the linux partition is mounted and writable in windows.
#
# The grubenv file is the GRUB Environment block. See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Environment-block.html.
# This is a preallocated 1024 byte file, padded with '#' on the last line, and with no trailing
# newline. If your system is properly set up to use 'grub-reboot', this file will have a line like
#   next_entry=
# grub-reboot, and this script, simply puts the desired entry here and adjusts the file size back to 1024 by
# truncating or extending the filler line.
#
# This script performs many sanity checks, and will not update your grubenv file is there is anything
# unexpected. But use at your own risk. Its been tested on a dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10
# system, configured such that 'grub-reboot' from Ubuntu will change the default on the next boot only.
# It has only been tried with boot entries as zero based grub menu item numbers. It could easily be
# extended to support menu item names or identifiers, as grub-reboot does, with some testing and by
# removing the check which requires a positive integer for the --menu argument.
#

PROG_NAME=${0##*/}

# grubenv is expected to be 1024 bytes
FILE_SIZE=1024

function Die
{
    echo $*
    exit 1
}

function Usage
{
    IFS=%

    while read line
    do
        echo $line
    done <<ENDUSAGE

Usage: $PROG_NAME [OPTIONS]

Set the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only

Options:
  -e, --entry       Desired grub menu entry for next boot only. Must be a 0 based 
                    grub menu item number. grub-reboot supports additional options,
                    but these are untested at this time and therefore disabled.
                    See 'man grub-reboot' for more details.
  -f, --file        Full path and name for the grubenv file. On the linux system, this
                    is typically /boot/grub/grubenv. On windows, this should be the windows
                    path to that file (the linux partition must be mounted and writable).
  -d, --diff        Display a diff of the original grubenv and the new one
  -r, --dry-run     Writes the new grubenv file to a temp file and displays its content.
                    No changes are made to the actual grubenv file.
  -h, --help        Display this usage message

Example: Assuming that you are running under cygwin and your linux partition containing /boot
is mounted on drive D, and that 0 is the grub menu item number for the desired next boot, then

    $PROG_NAME --file /cygdrive/D/boot/grub/grubenv --entry 0

will cause grub to choose the first menu item for the next boot only.

ENDUSAGE
}

function Main
{
    set +e

    declare grubEnvFile
    declare newEntry
    declare dryRun=false
    declare showDiff=false

    while [ $# -ne 0 ]
    do
        case ${1} in
        -e|--entry)
            shift
            newEntry=$1
            ;;
        -f|--file)
            shift
            grubEnvFile=$1
            ;;
        -d|--diff)
            showDiff=true
            ;;
        -r|--dry-run)
            dryRun=true
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            Usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        "")
            ;;
        *)
            Die "Unsupported argument $1"
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done

    [ ! -z $grubEnvFile ] || Die "Path to grubenv is required"
    [ -f $grubEnvFile ] || Die "File $grubEnvFile does not exist"

    # remove this check to allow menu item names/identifiers
    if ! [[ $newEntry =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
        Die "entry [$newEntry] must be a 0 based grub menu item"
    fi

    # Sanity check the current file size
    currentFileSize=$(stat -c %s "$grubEnvFile")
    [ $currentFileSize -eq $FILE_SIZE ] || Die "$grubEnvFile has unexpected size $currentFileSize"

    # Make sure the current file contains the next_entry= line
    cat $grubEnvFile | egrep "^next_entry=.*$" >/dev/null 2>&1 || Die "Did not find expected 'next_entry' in $grubEnvFile"

    # Get the old entry form the file
    oldEntry=$(cat $grubEnvFile | sed -E -n "s/^next_entry=(.*$)/\1/p")

    # Get lengths of old and new so we know how to adjust the filler line
    newEntryLen=$(echo $newEntry | awk '{print length}')
    oldEntryLen=$(echo $oldEntry | awk '{print length}')
    diffLen=$((newEntryLen-oldEntryLen))

    # Make sure the last line is the expected filler '######...'
    tail -n 1 $grubEnvFile | egrep "^#+$" >/dev/null 2>&1 || Die "Did not find expected filler line in $grubEnvFile"

    # Write the new file out to a temp file with the new next_entry value. 
    # We are operating on the temp file till all sanity checks pass, and
    # then we'll overwrite the existing file with the temp file.
    tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/grubenv.XXXXXX)
    cat $grubEnvFile | sed -E  "s/^next_entry=.*$/next_entry=${newEntry}/" > $tmpfile

    if [ $diffLen -gt 0 ]; then
        # new file will be too large. truncate it. we'll ensure that we still have a filler line
        # below, to make sure we did not truncate anything important
        truncate -s $FILE_SIZE $tmpfile
    elif [ $diffLen -lt 0 ]; then
        # we need to add chars to the filler line to get to 1024
        diffLen=$((-diffLen))
        extraFiller=$(printf "%${diffLen}s" '#' | tr ' ' '#')
        echo -n $extraFiller >> $tmpfile
    fi

    # make sure the new file has the expected next_entry
    cat $tmpfile | egrep "^next_entry=${newEntry}$" >/dev/null 2>&1 || Die "Unexpected error: replacement error"

    # make sure the new file is the correct size
    newFileSize=$(stat -c %s $tmpfile)
    [ $newFileSize -eq $FILE_SIZE ] || Die "Unexpected file $newFileSize size in the result"

    # Make sure the last line is the expected filler '######...'
    tail -n 1 $tmpfile | egrep "^#+$" >/dev/null 2>&1 || Die "Unexpected error: no filler line in result"

    if [ $showDiff = true ]; then
        echo "diff $grubEnvFile $tmpfile:"
        diff $grubEnvFile $tmpfile
    fi

    if [ $dryRun = true ]; then
        echo
        echo "Result in $tmpfile:"
        echo
        cat $tmpfile
    else
        mv $tmpfile $grubEnvFile
    fi
}

Main "$@"
```

I invoke this from a driver script which works from either Linux or Windows (Cygwin) called `winboot`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function IsWindows
{
    case `uname` in
        CYGWIN_NT-*)
            true
            ;;
        *)
            false
            ;;
    esac
}

set -e

if IsWindows; then
    win-grub-reboot --file /cygdrive/D/boot/grub/grubenv --entry 0
    shutdown --reboot now
else
    sudo grub-reboot 0
    sudo reboot now
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'll try out your answer once I've got time, but for now I'll accept it, as it is the closest thing to a complete answer as I've seen, and is excellently documented.

Comment: I've finally been able to test and confirm, this indeed works in my setup, using Paragon's linuxfs. I've also translated it to rust, available [at my github](https://github.com/Zoybean/win_grub_reboot)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem we have been facing for a long time in a CIP with dual-boot computers administered remotely.

Unfortunately, I can't come up with a complete solution, just another idea that might help to find a solution: Grub could get either the complete configuration or at least the configuration for "next boot" or/and "default boot" from a server in the LAN (via whichever protocol).

This would have the additional advantage of clarity and easier administration for larger pools...